# Получить значение msg.success из php (json_encode)

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма:

```html
<div id="addCommentContainer">
    <form id="addCommentForm" method="POST" action="">
        <label for="name">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

        <label for="messageBody">Текст сообщения</label>
        <textarea name="messageBody" id="messageBody" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <div class="buttons">
            <!--<input type="submit" id="preview" value="Предворительный просмотр">-->
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Я отправляю её в `php` для вставки данных в БД через `ajax` без перезагрузки страницы (Данные добавляются в таблицу БД корректно). Код скрипта:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addCommentForm').bind('submit', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "submit.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (msg) { //Данные отправлены успешно
                    if(msg.success){
                        //Отобразить новый комментарий
                    } else {
                        //Сообщение о не корректном вводе
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Не могу получить значение** `msg.success` в **if** из `php`.

Вот код `php`:

```js
$arr = $_POST;
$validates = Comment::validate($arr);
if ($validates) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO comment(name, email, messageBody) VALUES ('" . $arr['name'] . "', '" . $arr['email'] . "', '" . $arr['messageBody'] . "')");
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
}
```

Мой вопрос: подскажите новичку, возможно вся конструкция не верна, я уже голову сломал попытками.

Comment: `return json_encode(['success' => true])` ?

Comment: Консоль что говорит?

Comment: выполните console.log(msg) перед конструкцией if. Что показывает?

Comment: А еще можно открыть консоль на вкладке Network и после отправки запроса - посмотреть что вернул сервер (Response), те ли данные приходят которые вы ожидаете. Если не те - то проблема явно в коде на PHP, а это уже сужает круг поиска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно **явно** указать формат ответа от сервера.

Так как в вашем случае `json`, то нужно его и указать.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json', // вот так
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

[Подробнее о методе ajax](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_JSON-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

[Справка на русском о параметре dataType](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81#.D0.9F.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.80_dataType)

Так же советую после `echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));` выполнять принудительное завершение скрипта, вот так:

```
echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
die;
```

это даёт гарантию, что после вывода `json` больше ничего не попадёт в ответ и не сломает его структуру.

Comment: У него вообще не понятно, что в ответе приходит.

Comment: после этого: `dataType: 'json'` всё заработало, самый лаконичный и рабочий совет, `die;`, тоже воспользовался и это реально необходимо.